# How can I loop through a selected range of values in my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I don't want the loop to iterate over every row in the column, I just want to specify a small range of rows for the loop to iterate over for my data frame.

```
for row in df3:
    df3["Coordinates"] = df3["Address"].apply(nom.geocode) 
df3
df3.to_excel("new_excel_therealdeal.xlsx")
```

Comment: Can you use `if` to check for the current row and then break the loop when it reaches the row you want it to stop?

Answer (score 4):

you can slice the df row-wise (df.loc[1:3]) and then iterate over it and do your stuff over the row item.

```
for idx, row in df.loc[1:3].iterrows():
       print(row[col1], row[col2])  ### do your row wise operation here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df3['Coordinates']  = df3["Address"][start_range:end_range].apply(nom.geocode)

# example
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
df['new_columns'] = df['A'][0:2].apply(lambda x: x+5)
print(df['new_columns'])

#o/p
Out[12]: 
0    5.0
1    6.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
Name: new_columns, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a possible example. You can change the range based on your requirement.

```
# iloc[row slicing, column slicing]
df3.iloc[0:3, 1:4]
```